# Email signature using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add Email signature in body of mail when user clicks the button using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [email-links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links)?

```
<a href="mailto:contact@foo.bar&body=%0A%0AThis is my signature">Contact us</a>
```